# R Shiny: Avoid scrollbars when using googleVis charts in tabPanels

Tags: html, r, tabs, shiny, googlevis

Strangely enough I am getting a scrollbar on the right side of the page when I run the below shiny app:

```
shinyUI(
  fluidPage(
    tabsetPanel(
      tabPanel("Plot", htmlOutput("test")),
      tabPanel("Summary"),
      tabPanel("Table")
    )
  )
)

library(googleVis)
library(shiny)

shinyServer(function(input, output, session) {
  output$test <- renderGvis({
     gvisBubbleChart(Fruits, idvar="Fruit", 
                            xvar="Sales", yvar="Expenses",
                            colorvar="Year", sizevar="Profit",
                            options=list(
                              hAxis='{minValue:75, maxValue:125}',
                              vAxis='{minValue:0, maxValue:250}'
                              ,height=600,width=600)
     )  
  }) 
})
```

If I change from tabsetPanel layout to a pageWithSidebar layout the plot appears normally without the scrollbars. 
On a seperate note, if I do not specify the width and height in the options list I am getting two scrollbars, one vertical and one horizontal.

Is it possible to use googleVis charts within tabsetPanels without the scrollbars?

Comment: I also ran into this issue.  The workaround I used was to include a summary of the data below the chart.  Obviously, not as clean a response @jdharrison had, but the scroll bars can also be removed that way...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can set the `overflow` to hidden by adding a `style` argument to the `tabPanel` call:

```
library(googleVis)
library(shiny)
runApp(
  list(ui = fluidPage(
    tabsetPanel(
      tabPanel("Plot", htmlOutput("test"), style = "overflow:hidden;"),
      tabPanel("Summary"),
      tabPanel("Table")
    )
  )
  , server = function(input, output, session) {
    output$test <- renderGvis({
      gvisBubbleChart(Fruits, idvar="Fruit", 
                      xvar="Sales", yvar="Expenses",
                      colorvar="Year", sizevar="Profit",
                      options=list(
                        hAxis='{minValue:75, maxValue:125}',
                        vAxis='{minValue:0, maxValue:250}'
                        ,height=600,width=600)
      )  
    }) 
  })
)
```

[image]